# lavaan longitudinal invariance CFA with a 2-factor model in R

Tags: r, r-lavaan

I use the `longInvariance` function to asssess longitudinal invariance between two time points for interval data; and I am wondering how the correct `lavaan`/`semTools` `R`-code should look like.

It works when I look at one factor at a time; but it generates an error when examining  a two factor model.

Example code for one factor below:

```
  model.oneFactor <- '
  Factor1T1 =~ Item1 + Item2 + Item3
  Factor1T2 =~ Item1t2 + Item2t2 + Item3t2
  '

  # Create list of variables
  var1 <- c("Item1", "Item2", "Item3")
  var2 <- c("Item1t2", "Item2t2", "Item3t2")
  constrainedVar <- list(var1, var2)

  # Invariance of the same factor across timepoints
  longInvariance(model.oneFactor, auto=1, constrainAuto=TRUE, varList=constrainedVar, data=data, estimator="MLM", strict=TRUE)
```

However, when adding a second factor in the model generates an error. Example code for a two-factor model below:

```
  model.twoFactor <- '
  Factor1T1 =~ Item1 + Item2 + Item3
  Factor2T1 =~ Item4 + Item5 + Item6 + Item7
  Factor1T2 =~ Item1t2 + Item2t2 + Item3t2
  Factor2T2 =~ Item4t2 + Item5t2 + Item6t2 + Item7t2
  '

  # Create list of variables
  var1 <- c("Item1", "Item2", "Item3", "Item4", "Item5", "Item6", "Item7")
  var2 <- c("Item1t2", "Item2t2", "Item3t2", "Item4t2", "Item5t2", "Item6t2", "Item7t2")
  constrainedVar <- list(var1, var2)

  # Invariance of the same factor across timepoints
  longInvariance(model.twoFactor, auto=1, constrainAuto=TRUE, varList=constrainedVar, data=data, estimator="MLM", strict=TRUE)
```

The generated error is:

```
   Error in longInvariance(model.twoFactor, auto = 1, constrainAuto = TRUE,  : 
    The factor names of the same element of the 'varList' are not the same.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you also asked your question on the [lavaan Google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/lavaan/nfdatPgLLhc).

As it was answered there and written in the `semTools` [documentation](https://www.google.com/url?q=https%3A%2F%2Fcran.r-project.org%2Fweb%2Fpackages%2FsemTools%2FsemTools.pdf&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNE84EElHwR9aKilS9RN8f5q2gwS8Q), `semTools` only provides `longInvariance()` for one single scale. If you have two scales you need to specify the models by hand.